# How to enable caching with GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, header, http-headers

I want to enable public caching with google app engine. I've got the following response where performance significantly increased when starting to use the Cache-Control:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK =>
Cache-Control => public,max-age=86400
Content-Type => application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml
Expires => Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
Date => Sun, 10 Apr 2011 14:32:09 GMT
Server => Google Frontend
```

How can I now enable caching? Is it already enabled? Do I also need to add a future expires header? If so, how do I set the expires header? Thanks for any answer

Comment: Please don't crosspost here and on the groups without mentioning it in both places - otherwise, people waste time (theirs and yours) answering questions that have already been answered.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I deleted the other post since the question is now answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this enables caching - though you shouldn't be setting an expires header yourself at all unless it's accurate - just set the max-age, and let the caches and/or browser to determine the expiry date.